# how does one checkout a version of a single binary file in git?

Tags: git

I am familiar with the approach of retrieving a single file version from a git repository:

```
git checkout <hash> -- <path/file-name>
```

... and it works like a charm for all my code files.  I want to revert one the images I have in my repository and I'm not seeing any change in my binary file after running the git command.  I find out what commit the change is in

```
git log --stat
```

..., using '/<file-name>' in the git console, and then try to checkout the file as indicated above to no avail.

Are there special switches I'm supposed to use when retrieving binary versions in Git?

Comment: The two answers listed below seemed right to me as well.  Thanks for the answers; I'll look into what I must be doing wrong.  Perhaps I'm going after the wrong <hash>?

Comment: Indeed, it appears I was using the wrong <hash>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the same command should work for both text and binary files.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout <Hash> binary file works fine
```